# Error in eval(family$initialize) : y values must be 0 <= y <= 1

Tags: r, data-analysis, categorical-data

It was mentioned in the textbook that I need to convert the Satellite data into zeros and ones (if Y=0, then Y=0. But if Y is greater than or equal to 1, then Y=1), but I don't know how to do that. Am I missing something?

Here is my code:

```
library(icda)
data(horseshoecrabs)
crab=horseshoecrabs
head(crab)
??horeshoecrabs
probit=glm(Satellites ~ Weight, family=binomial(link="probit"), data=horseshoecrabs )
summary(probit)
```

This problem is from "An introduction to categorical data analysis" 2nd edition problem 3.8 in case that helps. My task is to report the fit for the probit model with weight as the predictor.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using the probit model, your response must be binary (i.e. it must be either 0 or 1). `Satellites` is not binary.

```
> horseshoecrabs$Satellites
  [1]  8  0  9  0  4  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 11  0 14  8  1  1  0  5  4  3  1  2  3  0  3  5  0  0  4  0  0  8  5  0  0  6  0  6  3
 [42]  5  6  5  9  4  6  4  3  3  5  5  6  4  5 15  3  3  0  0  0  5  3  5  1  8 10  0  0  3  7  1  0  6  0  0  3  4  0  5  0  0
 [83]  0  4  0  3  0  0  0  0  5  0  0  0  0  1  0  1  1  1  1  1  1  4  1  1  1  1  2  4  3  6  0  2  2  0 12  0  5  6  6  2  0
[124]  2  3  0  3  4  2  6  6  0  4 10  7  0  5  5  6  6  7  3  3  0  0  8  4  4 10  9  4  0  0  0  0  4  0  2  0  4  4  3  8  0
[165]  7  0  0  2  3  4  0  0  0
```

An **example** of probit with binary data is to consider the following coding: let's introduce a new binary variable `Satellites.binary` and consider Yes = 1 and No = 0. If at least one satellite exists (i.e. satellite > 0), we will consider the observation a success and code the value as 1. If a satellite does note exist, we will code the value to be 0.

```
# Consider Satellite to be Yes if Satellite > 0 and No if Satellite = 0
# Code Yes = 1, No = 0
Satellites.binary = ifelse(horseshoecrabs$Satellites > 0, 1, 0)
> Satellites.binary
  [1] 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1
 [63] 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1
[125] 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0
```

Now with this variable, we can construct a probit model

```
probit = glm(Satellites.binary ~ horseshoecrabs$Weight, family=binomial(link="probit"))
> summary(probit)
Call:
glm(formula = Satellites.binary ~ horseshoecrabs$Weight, family = binomial(link = "probit"))

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-2.1436  -1.0774   0.5336   0.9196   1.6216  

Coefficients:
                      Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)            -2.2383     0.5116  -4.375 1.22e-05 ***
horseshoecrabs$Weight   1.0990     0.2151   5.108 3.25e-07 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 225.76  on 172  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 195.46  on 171  degrees of freedom
AIC: 199.46

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4
```

**Note:** As mentioned earlier, this is just an example and it may not be the correct model for you. This was created for illustrative purposes to demonstrate how to use the probit model.

Comment: this is nice.  I'd recommend including the binary variable in the original data frame: `horseshoecrabs <- transform(horseshoecrabs, sat_binary=ifelse(Satellites>0,1,0))`

Comment: @BenBolker: Yes I agree, this is a good suggestion. Thank you.